# Checking if the value in negative in a spanner.NullInt64

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I have a value in **spanner.NullInt64** type column.
How can I check if the value is a negative number less than 0.

I can't just do an operation like **< 0** on a spanner.NullInt type column.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are talking about `spanner.NullInt64` in the Go client library, a check for a negative number would look like this:

```
var i spanner.NullInt64
i = spanner.NullInt64{Int64: 1, Valid: true}
// This will be false
negative := i.Valid && i.Int64 < 0

i = spanner.NullInt64{Int64: -1, Valid: true}
// This will be true.
negative = i.Valid && i.Int64 < 0

// This represents a NULL and would also be false.
i = NullInt64{Valid: false}
// This will be false.
negative = i.Valid && i.Int64 < 0
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was asking. This is very helpful. Thank you